# Python call a imported function from a different .py file, but the imported function cannot see the other imported moduel in main file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function defined in a different file **nhpp_next_arrival.py**, which contains a function. The important thing to notice is that I am using **numpy** package.

```
def nhpp_next_arrival(t,Lambda, h_lam):
    # current starting time t
    # rate handle h_lam
    # Lambda a majorizing function/constant

    U = np.random.uniform()
    V = np.random.uniform()

    t = t - np.log(U)/Lambda


    while V > h_lam(t)/Lambda:

        t = t - np.log(U)/Lambda
        U = np.random.uniform()
        V = np.random.uniform()

    return t
```

I imported this function in a different file as the following

```
import numpy as np
from nhpp import *

#Call nhpp_next_arrival
t_arrival = nhpp_next_arrival(t=t, Lambda=max_arrival, h_lam=h_arr_total)
```

**Then I got the following error message.**

> `U = np.random.uniform()` NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Thank you!

Comment: is `numpy` imported in the nhpp_next_arrival.py file?

Comment: Should I import it at the very beginning? I imported it in the if statement that says if __name__=='__main__'.

Comment: Yes, import `numpy` in the nhpp_next_arrival.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confused with a C `#include` (or something similar).

Your code is using `numpy.random` at `nhpp_next_arrival.py`, so you should have at its top

```
import numpy as np
```

Even though you imported it before the import to this file, when the interpreter sees

```
from nhpp import *
```

it doesn't import the packages into the namespace of that module.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when calling a function "add_datepart" in a module named "structured.py" after importing the module into jupyter notebook.

I imported numpy as np in the notebook at the very beginning, then import "structured.py", then call "add_datepart", and there comes the error

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined.
```

**SOLUTION:**
add `import numpy as np` at the beginning of "structured.py", namely the module you are importing.

**EXPLANATION:**
This paragraph is what I want to highlight. The NameError we get is mostly due to name searching mechanism of the interpreter, the LEGB rule. When encountering a name (np) in a function, the interpreter first look it in the local scope, then in the global scope of **the module("structured_modified.py", or in your case "nhpp.py")**, it will not resolve "np" in another module or script's global scope(the global scope of the main file or the notebook file).
`from nbpp import *` only binds the function's name in the main file's namespace, it doesn't necessarily mean the function can make use of names in the main file. So if you wanna call a funtion utilizing some package, you'd make sure the package is imported in the module where the funtion resides.